# Get Chrome Extension to work on different tab?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, background, manifest.json

I'm pretty new to programming chrome extensions. The one that I have programmed works as I would like it, however you need to be clicked into the specific tab in order for it to work. For example, I can't just have the site open while perusing the internet in a separate window.

The webpage that this is for is my company's service check page where different teams from the company post issues that they've had for others to see and work on. My extension reads this page for any issues that have gone unnoticed for more than ten minutes and notifies the user using a toast popup. I think it is the active tab that makes it so the extension runs on whichever tab is currently clicked into, but I am not sure. Is there anyway I can make it so this extension runs without having to be in the tab?

Here is the code I have, any suggestions for how the extension is set up are welcome as well:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Nagios Notifications",
  "description": "This extension allows a notification to be sent when a Nagios check reaches 10 minutes duration",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": { "16": "img/icon_16.png",
              "48": "img/icon_48.png",
              "128": "img/icon_128.png"},
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click to show notifications!"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://eotnagios/nagios/*"],
      "js": ["js/contentscript.js", "js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js", "js/jquery-toast-plugin-master/src/jquery.toast.js"],
      "css": ["js/jquery-toast-plugin-master/src/jquery.toast.css"],
      "all_frames": true,
      "run_at" : "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "background",
    "notifications",
    "tabs",
    "webNavigation",
    "http://eotnagios/nagios/*"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "img/*.png",
    "css/*.css",
    "js/*.js"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js", "js/jquery-toast-plugin-master/src/jquery.toast.js", "js/background.js"]
  }
}
```

background.js

```
//When frame updates
chrome.webNavigation.onReferenceFragmentUpdated.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subject: "checkTable"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
  })
})

//On page load
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subject: "checkTable"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
  })
})

//When extension is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subject: "checkTable"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
  })
})

//When page is clicked
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function () {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {subject: "checkTable"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    })
  })
})
```

contentscript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject == "checkTable" || request.subject == "notifications") {
      var table = document.getElementsByClassName("status")[1];
      var durations = [];
      if (typeof table !== 'undefined'){
      for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        var tableRow = {};
        //rows
        for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
          if (j == 4 && i != 0) {
          tableRow["duration"] = col.innerHTML;
          }
          else if (j == 1 && i != 0) {
            tableRow["service"] = col.innerHTML;
          }
        }
        if (Object.keys(tableRow).length == 2){
          durations.push(tableRow);
        }
      }
      for (var k = 0; k < durations.length; k++) {
        var acknowledged = "no";
        var time = durations[k]["duration"].split(" ")
        for (var item = 0; item < time.length; item++) {
          if (time[item].slice(-1) == "h") {
            var hours = time[item];
            if (hours.length == 2) {
              hours = parseInt(hours.substr(0, 1));
            }
            else if (hours.length == 3) {
              hours = parseInt(hours.substr(0, 2));
            }
          }
          else if (time[item].slice(-1) == "m") {
            var minutes = time[item];
            if (minutes.length == 2) {
              minutes = parseInt(minutes.substr(0, 1));
            }
            else if (minutes.length == 3) {
              minutes = parseInt(minutes.substr(0, 2));
            }

            var hourMinutes = hours * 60;
            minutes += hourMinutes;

            if (minutes > 10) {
              var check = durations[k]["service"];
              check = check.split(" ");
              for (var x = 0; x < check.length; x++){
                if (check[x].substr(0, 4) == "href") {
                  var line = check[x].split(";");
                  var host = line[1];
                  host = host.split("=")[1];
                  host = host.split("&")[0];
                  line = line[2];
                  line = line.split("#");
                  line = line[0].split(">")
                  line = line[0].split("=");
                  line = line[1].split("\"");
                  var service = line[0];
                }
                else if (check[x].substr(0, 3) == "src") {
                  var line = check[x].split("/");
                  line = line[3].split("\"");
                  line = line[0];
                  if (line == "ack.gif") {
                    acknowledged = "yes";
                  }}}}
              }
            }

            var serviceCheck = {"duration" : minutes, "service" : service, "host" : host, "acknowledged" : acknowledged};
            if (minutes > 10) {
              var toastColor;
              if (minutes <= 30) {
                toastColor = "orange";
              }
              else if (30 < minutes && minutes <= 60) {
                toastColor = "orangered";
              }
              else if (60 < minutes && minutes <= 120) {
                toastColor = "darkRed";
              }
              else {
                toastColor = "red";
              }

              //var notified = notifications(serviceCheck["host"], serviceCheck["service"]);
              if (serviceCheck["acknowledged"] == "no"){
            $.toast({
              text: "<strong>Minutes passed:</strong> " + minutes + " <strong>Service:</strong> " + service + " <strong>Host:</strong> " + host + " <strong>Acknowledged:</strong> " + acknowledged,
              hideAfter: false,
              position: 'bottom-right',
              bgColor: toastColor,
              textColor: 'white'
              });
            }
            }
              sendResponse(serviceCheck);
          }
        }
        }
      }
    )
```

Comment: You are only ever sending your message to the active tab, which won't necessarily be the page with the content script. Do you mean to be sending a message to some particular page? Or just having the content script do its thing automatically?

Comment: I'd like the content script to do its thing automatically but on a particular page no matter what window I'm in. Currently my background script is sending a message on page refresh or frame refresh which then triggers the content script which I just assumed was how it worked.

Comment: ok i'm an idiot, I had the run_at in my manifest.json and didn't even utilize it correctly haha. So the content script runs automatically now and that fixed my problem. If you want to just copy and paste what you said into the answer box I can select it.